# Issue in add listener

Tags: javascript

Hi can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong in this line

```
let div = document.createElement( ‘div’ );
div.className = ‘label’;
div.textContent = ‘+’;
div.type=‘button’;
div.id=‘label6’;
div.onclick=addEventListener(“click”,otherscript.function()); --->this line
```

function not call once I press the runtime button

Comment: You either assign a function to `element.onclick` or you call `element.addEventListener` passing an event name and a function. Maybe this helps: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#examples

Comment: you are already defining an eventListener with `.onclick` ... So something like `div.onclick=function() {...}` should work. Didn't test it, but this should point you in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

You are using onClick and addEventListener in the wrong way, first off, you shouldnt call otherscript.function using `()` but instead just pass a reference by leaving the `()` away

Second off, you should not combine onclick and addEventListener

### How to use onClick

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

```
div.onclick = otherscript.function;
```

### How to use addEventListener

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_addeventlistener.asp

```
div.addEventListener('click', otherscript.function);
```

### Working example

The following codepen contains a working example using your given code, but using the addEventListener and onClick technique, The addEventListener one is commented because you can only use one at the same time

https://codepen.io/lucdewit/pen/popOdzy

Comment: I try this but nothing happened

Comment: @HiLamb can you create a [codepen](https://codepen.io) containing the code you tried? that way i can see whats wrong with it and actually try it

Comment: @HiLamb I added a working codepen example to show how it does indeed work, let me know if u can figure it out from that

Comment: Too many integrations with other scripts so it would be difficult for me to add a code in codepen :)

Comment: div.addEventListener("click",uiHandler.addConnectionBtns);
here is the line which I'm trying but nothing happened

Comment: @HiLamb can you replace uiHandler.addConnectionBtns with a testing function that does an alert() (like the one in my codepen), maybe its just the uiHandler.addConnectionBtns function itself thats broken, and not the click event

Comment: @HiLamb Please keep me updated on if you fixed the issue, im curious if it does work with a testing function that creates an alert()

Comment: it calls when you add eventlistener like initialize button runtime but clickable functionality is not working